# Why don't some diacritics get stripped?

Tags: .net, string, diacritics

I am using the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/249126/983064) to remove special characters from words and change them to a simple form. This works pretty nicely for many basic accents, e.g.

```
Malmö becomes "Malmo"
München becomes "Munchen"
Åge becomes "Age"
```

However this doesn't work on some other characters, for example:

```
Strømsgodset remains "Strømsgodset"
Kulħadd remains "Kulħadd"
```

Is there any reason why these characters are not converted like the others?

Also is there any way to similarly convert 'combined' characters such as:

```
æ -> ae
ẞ -> ss
```

Comment: Because linguists and bureaucrats at the Unicode Consortium decided so.

Comment: According to your second question how to map them to a pair of other characters, use a `Dictionary<char, string>`. Then it's easy: `foreach(var kv in dict) text=text.Replace(kv.Key.ToString(),kv.Value)`

Comment: That will work if you know all the special characters in every language in the world.

Comment: @Gigi There are no special characters. What you said is like saying that sushi is special food.

Comment: What is your final goal? Why do you need to convert letters to the form you call simple? BTW, Kullħadd has one more `L`.

Comment: To match search results regardless of diacritics. Kullħadd is the newspaper, Kulħadd means "everyone" (I'm Maltese :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the [Normalization chart](http://unicode.org/charts/normalization/) written by the Unicode Consortium doesn't have the decompositions you want, and Microsoft used that chart (or more probably a text version of that chart, or perhaps an older version of that chart, but these are details).

I don't know the reason, because I'm not a linguist, but I do hope that there are enough good linguists in the Unicode Consortium to do the correct choices.

Note that collation tables are separate from normalization tables, so you can have that:

```
int res = string.Compare("æ", "ae", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
```

is `0`... so `æ == ae`, and `ħ == h`

You can even `IndexOf`, using the collation:

```
int ix = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(
    "Ad aeternitatem", 
    "æter", 
    CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace); // 3
```

and ignoring case:

```
int ix = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(
    "Ad Aeternitatem", 
    "æter", 
    CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase); // 3
```

Comment: For these 'double characters' that makes sense, but does this also hold true for the others (e.g. ħ)?

Comment: @gigi The fact that it is graphically similar to a `h`, doesn't mean that it is an `h`. Would you like the `$` simbol to be decomposed to a `S` plus a `|` ? :-)

Comment: Yes? :) Kidding apart, there are practical reasons why it is useful to take advantage of the graphical (but not semantic) similarity, e.g. search.

Comment: @gigi for search there is the CompareInfo.IndexOf . If you want I can post an example. It uses collation, not normalization

Comment: By all means, please do :)